# How to visit a link-local website on CentOS7? while in windows it just works with [fe80::x:x:x] in the browser

Tags: apache, url, firefox, ipv6, link-local

I run apache on CentOS and Listen 80. And I can visit the website using 127.0.0.1.

I tried several ways to visit the website using ipv6 link-local address:

1. [fe80::x:x:x]    not work
2. [fe80::x:x:x%eth0]   not work
3. [fe80::x:x:x%eth0]:80    not work
4. [fe80::x:x:x%25eth0]:80   not work
5. http://[fe80::x:x:x%eth0]:80   not work
   ....

Just more ways like above, no way works.

Any help?

BTW, I tried apache and ipv6 on windows 10. It works with  [fe80::x:x:x] visiting the website..amazing!

Comment: [similar question](https://superuser.com/a/367788)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i access the web server or website using link local IPv6 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446953/how-do-i-access-the-web-server-or-website-using-link-local-ipv6-address)

Comment: @iNullPointer Thx, I've seen that question before, but in windows, it works. So I just wonder the diffirence ipv6 performs between windows and Linux. :)

Comment: You can't. Use a ULA or global address instead.